# Create JSON from SQL result for API

Tags: json, go

I'm very new to Go so hopefully this is simple to fix. I want to build a JSON value from rows in an SQL database. It doesn't have to be SQL but I'm looking for a way to generate a list of structs or a container that holds many values in order to generate JSON from it.

For example, an HTTP GET request to "/post" would return:

```
{
  "posts": [
    { "title": "First title", "created_by": "User1" },
    { "title": "My second post", "created_by": "User1"}
  ]
}
```

I don't know what's the proper way to do this. I've tried other ways using an array of pointers but it doesn't come out correctly.  So far it prints out the correct values for each struct but the resulting Marshal is empty `[{},{},{}]`

Please go easy on me :)

**example.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "time"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)


type Post struct {
    name string `json:"name"`
    created_by string `json:"created_by"`
    created_at time.Time `json:"created_at"`
}

type Posts []Post

func main() {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:1234@/blog?parseTime=true")
    if err != nil { panic(err.Error()) }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil { panic(err.Error()) }

    rows, err := db.Query("select title, created_by, created_at from post")
    if err != nil { panic(err.Error()) }
    defer rows.Close()

    var posts Posts
    for rows.Next() {            
        var post Post
        err := rows.Scan(&post.name, &post.created_by, &post.created_at)
        if err != nil { panic(err.Error()) }
        fmt.Printf("name=%s, created_by=%s, created_at=%s\n", post.name, post.created_by, post.created_at)
        posts = append(posts, post)                  
    }    

    data, err := json.Marshal(posts)    
    if err != nil { panic(err.Error()) }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
}
```

Comment: I just tried to Marshal a single Post and that doesn't work either.  I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fields aren't exported, so the `json` package can't see them.

See [50 Shades of Go](http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/index.html#unexp_struct_field_enc) for a longer explanation and others common gotchas.

Comment: Well, an unexported field is the `private` equivalent of other languages, so it is absolutely normal another package can't see it. It would defy the definition of `private` attribute otherwise…

Comment: I was referring to using style (Capitalization) to change behavior rather than a keyword (private like you said) or a symbol (Nim language uses *). Just something to figure out when learning a new language :)

Comment: Well… not adding a keyword or symbol to denote private state is shorter to write, faster to read, and in the end simpler. That may be the best example of "Convention over configuration".